# Transcendency of certain integrals

Tags: transcendental-number-theory

Let $p$ be an even monic polynomial with rational coefficients of degree at least $4$.
Can the integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-p(x)}dx$$
be an algebraic number? Is anything known about transcendency of such integrals?

Comment: The simplest case, perhaps, is $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^4}dx = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}\Gamma(3/4)}$$.  Can this be proved transcendental?

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: I really know no results on the subject, except integral of $e^{-x^2}$, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Following the "Related" links generated on the right here, I find http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209936/transcendence-of-gamma1-3-gamma1-4?rq=1 so that this simplest case is transcendental, since it is essentially $\Gamma(1/4)$.  Also $\Gamma(1/6)$ which we get from $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-x^6)dx$.

Comment: @Gerld Edgar: Thanks for the reference, I did not know this result.

Comment: These values are all **exponential periods**.  See Sec. 7.2 in
https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/TranscendencePeriods.pdf  
Michel Waldschmidt,"Transcendence of periods: the state of the art"  _Pure Appl. Math. Q._ **2** (2006), no. 2, part 2, 435--463

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: Thanks for the reference. This confirms that little is known about them.